# PHP thousand separator formatting for generated page from xlsx

Tags: php, formatting, xlsx, export-to-html

Ty mail2bapi, :)

Im using `SimpleXLSX` and example script below in code i added this `$x = number_format($r);`

Just need the numbers to have thousand separator
252252732
to
252,252,732

IM not good with PHP, really appreciate any help

Plus some columns are empty and dates like so 23.01.2020, I think this is what is causing the issue

[XMLS File](https://ln2.sync.com/dl/872eae700/se9xcq3n-6zmn24ud-vhg3kcvv-pni8h4nv)
[simplexlsx](https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsx)

Error: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, array given in

Error: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

```
<?php
require_once 'SimpleXLSX.php';

if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse('book.xlsx') ) {
    echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="3" style="border-collapse: collapse">';
    foreach( $xlsx->rows() as $r ) {
        $x = number_format($r);
        echo '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', $x ).'</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
    // or $xlsx->toHTML();  
} else {
    echo SimpleXLSX::parseError();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using number_format() function correctly. Change following code from -

```
$x = number_format($r);
```

to

```
$x = number_format($r, 0, ".", ",");
```

for more information visit [PHP number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

**EDIT**

As you mentioned your row could have a different type of values, it is better to check the value for numeric.

Try this code

```
<?php
require_once 'SimpleXLSX.php';

if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse('book.xlsx') ) {
     echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="3" style="border-collapse: collapse">';
    foreach( $xlsx->rows() as $rowValue ) {
       echo "<tr>";
       // As $rowValue is an array  
       foreach($rowValue as $value){
          // Check for number_format
          if(is_numeric($value)){
            $x = number_format($value, 0, ".", ",");
            echo "<td>".$x."</td>";
          }else{
            echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
          }
       }
       echo "</tr>";  
    }
    echo "</table>";

    // or $xlsx->toHTML();  
} else {
    echo SimpleXLSX::parseError();
}
```

Hope these resolve your issue.

Comment: Still gives the same error "Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, array given in" Plus some columns are empty or to short in numbers to format.

Comment: Can you show the output of print_r($r);. Place it just under the foreach loop.

Comment: Array ( [0] => 20.03.2020 [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => )  It seems broken as it has 3 colums, one row with dates one row with numbers in the millions, and 3rd are empty. We need it to ignore the dates  23.01.2020
:(

Comment: Hi, it has, Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). I added a dl link of the xmls if that helps?

Comment: You got the error because of variable $r in foreach loop. replace it with $rowValue or copy the updated code. It should be good now.

Comment: Hi, it has a blank page and nothing else there, and there are no logs either, and source code empty. The other thing is that worries me more is it needs to have the table formating, I'll never be able to get that into a formatted table again. So I would be better not to worry about it and use what i have without thousand separators in it . Ty thought

Comment: You are getting empty page because you are not printing value of $x. I think you can do the table formating as per your need.

Comment: Hi, im not good at programming :( it errors if adding it in the formating    echo '<tr><td class="sep">'.implode('</td><td class="sep">', $x ).'</td></tr>';
    echo '</table>';

Comment: Code is updated for rendering the table. Copy and run it.

Comment: Ty so so much, that's amazing. I gave +1 but got this :( Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Vote does not matter, I am happy that it helped you :)